# Development EGL apps for Omap4 that use PowerVR

Tags: c++, opengl-es, egl, omap, pandaboard

I have Pandaboard and I handle with PowerVR support on OMAP4, and I have tried Imagination Examples successfully. But I was wondering, how to write my own code and development apps to Pandaboard or Omap4 on my host machine, so cross-compilation?

Is the solution PowerVR SDK? So, How?

NOTE:
Ubuntu 11.10 runs on Pandaboard(armhf).
Ubuntu 12.04 run on HostMachine(x86)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll need a cross-toolchain for ARM. PowerVR SDK is just SDK for using OpenGL ES on a target platfrom (headers/libraries/drivers/examples).